# Kubernetes health check outside container

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

Can I do liveness or readiness kind of health check from out of the container. I mean, can I stop traffic to pods and restart containers in case application is not accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Http Request Liveness Probe and TCP Liveness Probe can be used to see if your application running inside of the container is reachable from the outside world:

```
pods/probe/http-liveness.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-http
spec:
  containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: k8s.gcr.io/liveness
    args:
    - /server
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 8080
        httpHeaders:
        - name: X-Custom-Header
          value: Awesome
      initialDelaySeconds: 3
      periodSeconds: 3
```

See [this piece of documentation on configuring probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/). Does that answer your question?